# Is there a purpose in calling super() from a basic python class?

Tags: python

I have somewhat of a strange question here. Let's say I'm making a simple, basic class as follows:

```python
class MyClass(object):

    def __init__(self):
        super(MyClass, self).__init__()
```

Is there any purpose in calling `super()`? My class only has the default `object` parent class. The reason why I'm asking this is because my IDE automagically gives me this snippet when I create a new class. I usually remove the `super()` function because I don't see any purpose in leaving it. But maybe I'm missing something ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not obliged to call `object.__init__` (via `super` or otherwise). It does nothing.

However, the purpose of writing that snippet in that way in an `__init__` function (or any function that calls the superclass) is to give you some flexibility to change the superclass without modifying that code.

So it doesn't buy you much, but it does buy you the ability to change the superclass of `MyClass` to a different class whose `__init__` likewise accepts no-args, but which perhaps *does* do something and does need to be called by subclass `__init__` functions. All without modifying your `MyClass.__init__`.

Your call whether that's worth having.

Also in this particular example you can leave out `MyClass.__init__` entirely, because yours does nothing too.